# Azure DevOps pipeline upload to FTP after create directory on remote server

Tags: azure-devops

I developed a .net core console application and I want to deliver it to a FTP server.

I managed it in Azure Devops with FTP Upload task. All good here.

But before upload content to FTP, I want to make sure that remote directory exists, if not then create.

I put command `mkdir test` in FTP command but I got error that command is unknown and deployment is not done

[image]

[image]

How to achieve that ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm just about positive that this Task is buggy and custom FTP Commands do not work at all. However, if the directory you specify in "Remote directory" does not exist it will be created so don't worry about doing a `mkdir`.